# Is it possible to remove a FieldSet and then re-Add it again? How?

Tags: java, click, fieldset

I got a screen that is shown according to what the costumer wants. So it depends on costumers needs.
The problem is, I have to remove 3 FieldSets when I click on "Clean Fields" button. To re-add them later when costumer clicks on "Search" button.
But when I try to remove, it says "Cannot set the FieldSet's form to null" as an IllegalArgumentException. Do you guys have any idea to help me out?

ps: If is there any Brazilians, maybe I can explain it in Portuguese.

public boolean onCleanClick() {

```
    this.form.remove(fsResult1);
    this.form.remove(fsResult2);
    this.form.remove(fsSubmits);
    this.profile1.setValue("0");
    this.profile2.setValue("0");
    return true;
}
```

public boolean onComparaPerfisClick(){

```
            fsSubmits.setShowBorder(false);
            fsSubmits.setColumns(2);
            fsSubmits.add(submitProfile1);
            fsSubmits.add(submitProfile2);

            form.add(fsSubmits, 2);

            fsResult1.add(processProfile1);
            fsResult1.setShowBorder(false);
            fsResult2.add(processProfile2);
            fsResult2.setShowBorder(false);

            form.add(fsResult1);
            form.add(fsResult2);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could do it.
I didn't find a way to remove a fieldSet from a form, instead of it, i added the fieldset on form without a thing
when i needed i added stuff, and when i clicked on clear button, i removed stuff from fieldset, and nothing from the form